# Error: File `IEEEtran.cls' not found

Tags: ieeetran, macos

I'm completely new to latex so please bare with me.

I'm getting the error "File `IEEEtran.cls' not found." for the line `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` -- although I have downloaded the IEEEtran package and placed it inside my working directory (the same file in which my main.tex file is in) and in Macintosh HD/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex folder.

I have also used the `sudo texhash` command, but I am still experiencing the error, and I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: IEEEtran is part of texlive so you would not normally need to download anything, or at most install it via `tlmgr` or the mactex utility

Comment: I used the command ```sudo tlmgr install IEEEtran``` but I'm getting the message: tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package IEEEtran not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: the tlmgr package name is `ieeetran` all lowercase it should install ieeetran:
        texmf-dist/doc/latex/ieeetran/IEEEtrantools_doc.txt
        texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/ieeetran/IEEEtran.bst
        texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/ieeetran/IEEEtranN.bst
        texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/ieeetran/IEEEtranS.bst
        texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/ieeetran/IEEEtranSA.bst
        texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/ieeetran/IEEEtranSN.bst
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/ieeetran/IEEEtran.cls
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/ieeetran/IEEEtrantools.sty

Comment: Well using the right command fixed the earlier issue, but introduced a new one that says "File `algorithm.sty' not found."

Comment: `tlmgr install algorithms` (with an s)   You must have installed a minimal texlive, it's much simpler to install `texlive-full` and avoid all these issues

Comment: Thank you! I've been continously getting messages such as: "File `inconsolata.sty' not found." or "File `cleveref' not found." so I'll fix those issues by installing the files, but is there a way that I can avoid these continous stream of messages by downloading something?

Comment: Everything cleared, thank you for your help @DavidCarlisle!

Comment: as I say you can install everything at the start, I think you can still do `tlmgr install --all` or some such now

Comment: I trust your main take-away from this posting is that installing a full [MacTeX distribution](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) right away tends to save a lot of time later on.